# Pygame not working on Mac when calling 'pygame.display.set_mode'

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I have tried for a long time to solve this problem, I even found some similar topics in stackoverflow, but nothing help me.

I'm trying to install pygame on my MacBook Pro OS X 10.9.4: the installation itself actually went fine, but it’s enough to me to digit on my terminal the following lines that I receive an error:

```
>>>import pygame

>>>pygame.init()

  (6,0)

>>>pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
```

The error is the following:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 263'
*** First throw call stack:

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929eb25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff94491e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929eb10c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b20ce95 _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 1403
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b20ba21 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 3720
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b0e7400 -[NSWindow _commonInitFrame:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 882
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b0e6882 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1054
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b0e6458 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45
    8   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib                  0x0000000102a2e21e -[SDL_QuartzWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 279
    9   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib                  0x0000000102a2bc63 QZ_SetVideoMode + 1417
    10  libSDL-1.2.0.dylib                  0x0000000102a22f71 SDL_SetVideoMode + 906
    11  display.so                          0x0000000102a71317 set_mode + 263
    12  Python                              0x00000001000c2f7d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21485
    13  Python                              0x00000001000c4f93 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    14  Python                              0x00000001000c50b6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    15  Python                              0x00000001000e946c PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 380
    16  Python                              0x00000001000e96ce PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 78
    17  Python                              0x00000001000e9ee1 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 161
    18  Python                              0x0000000100100bfd Py_Main + 3101
    19  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 Python + 3860
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6

I’m aware that it must be something with the SDL (that I installed properly).
I followed the suggestion made in a similar post to add the line

```
>>> os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']= ‘x11'
```

I get the same error.
If I write the same line with ‘Quartz’ (the mac video driver) is the same.
I tried this link that should have fixed the SDL problem but it didn’t work—> http://www.noquarterarcade.com/xcode-sdl-development-setup and other similar.
I searched a lot in the internet but I couldn’t find any match with my problem! I would really like to be able to use pygame on my mac and not on my old linux computer!
Thank you a lot!

Comment: I suggest trying out SDL 2.x instead of 1.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem following these instructions: (working for a the latest versions 10.9 and 10.10 of OSX)

1 )Create and add the following to ~/.bash_profile:

```
# Homebrew binaries now take precedence over Apple defaults
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

2)Install Apple Xcode command line tools:
xcode-select --install

3)Install XQuartz

4)Install homebrew:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

5)Install Python3 "proper" and packages we’ll need for installing PyGame from bitbucket:
brew install python3 hg sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi

6)Install PyGame:
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

7)Restart the Mac for XQuartz changes

I post it in case someone else has this same problem and read this post!! I hope that can be useful!